# Jquery On Hover: Fade background with text overlay

Tags: jquery, html, hidden, fade, onhover

I am trying to create a rollover effect that fades the image to 20% opacity and also overlaying text on top of the div. I have been able to make it fade, and reveal the text but for some reason it doesn't work well when they are combined. The closest thing that I have found to what I am trying to do is this: [http://damiencorrell.com/](http://damiencorrell.com) except for I am trying to get the background to fade to 20%. Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code you can post? It will be much easier to help you if you show what you already have.

Comment: Yes... here is a link to what I have. http://geoffjohnsondesign.com/inprogress/ 

Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
// change yourimage for your "#imageid" or ".imageclass"
$('yourimage').hover(function(){
  // fade to 0.2 ( 20% ) in 300ms
  $(this).fadeTo(300, 0.2);
}, function(){
  // restore opacity to 1 im 300ms
  $(this).fadeTo(300, 1);
});
```